# How to find parameters of sigmoid function given two thresholds?

Tags: sigmoid-curve, constrained-optimization

Let's say I start with a sigmoid function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp{\frac{-(x-c)}{d}}}$$

where the upper limit is 1 and lower limit 0, how can I for example find the appropriate values of the parameters $c,d$ such that

1. at $x=R_1$ for given $R_1$, e.g., at $x=5$, $f(x)=0.01$
2. at $x=R_2$ for given $R_2$, e.g., at $x=20$, $f(x)=0.99$

assuming this is sufficient information to define $c,d$?

Comment: Three unknowns $b,c,d$ so at least three observations

Comment: @Henry - updated to remove $b$, which isn't necessary for the behaviour I stated

Comment: Two unknowns $c,d$ so at least two observations

Comment: @Henry updated title to reflect the body

Comment: Re-expressing the information in terms of $-\log(1/f-1)=x/d-c/d$ gives a system of linear equations for $(c/d,1/d).$ Apply standard linear algebra results.

Comment: The $c$ and $d$ parameters can be identified through the log-odds ratios of the usual logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

In your reformulated question, two distinct error-free observations are enough:

$y= \frac{1}{1+\exp{\frac{-(x-c)}{d}}} \iff x=c+d \log_e(\frac 1y -1)$ provided $0<y<1$

so $d = \dfrac{x_2-x_1}{\log_e(\frac 1{y_2} -1)-\log_e(\frac 1{y_1} -1)}$ and $c=\dfrac{x_1\log_e(\frac1{y_2}-1)-x_2\log_e(\frac 1{y_1} -1)}{\log_e(\frac 1{y_2} -1)-\log_e(\frac 1{y_1} -1)}$

Comment: I tried these formulae with $x_1=0, y_1=0.01, x_2=20, y_2=0.99$ and got $c=10, d=-2.176221801855094$. Then if I call $f(x)$ with this $c,d$ I find $f(0) = 0.99$, $f(20) = 0.01$, the mirror of the desired output

Comment: @VainmondeDeCourtenay Perhaps I reversed a sign

Comment: Yes, doing the algebra in my head, there's a sign goes astray. Easily done.